# set of non-overlapping substrings of a string, **which include repeated substrings** …

Tags: combinatorics

Say, you have a string like: aabcaabcab

Which you could split as:

1) (aab)(c)(aab)(c)(a)(b)

2) (a)(ab)(c)(a)(ab)(c)(ab)

3) (a)(abc)(a)(abc)(a)(b)

4) (aabc)(aabc)(a)(b)

5) (aabc)(aabc)(ab)

...

The elements of all substrings must (naturally enough! ;-)) belong to the universe of elements of the initial string (only a start and end metacharacter is introduced in the splitting process) and the number of substrings must be less than the number of elements of the string. All those orderly chained substrings could be naturally encoded in a run-length fashion in an obvious way.

Notice that that problem isn't exactly a combinatoric "set cover" or Knapsack kind of problem, nor it is exactly a substring search one, which could be approached using suffix trees  (allisons.org/ll/AlgDS/Tree/Suffix/)

Which algorithm would give as outcome an array of all those splitting options given a string?

I could imagine this is a topic of research in lossless compression and data analysis algorithms useful in text processing and genetics

lbrtchx

http://math.stackexchange.com: non-overlapping substrings

Comment: Is there any real meaning to each of the letters above?  If not, then why not simplify the question to ask about ways to break into substrings of the string `abcdefghij` instead?  For this problem, imagine placing an open parenthesis at the beginning, end parenthesis at the end, and empty spaces between each letter, and picking from those a subset of the spaces where you will put `)(`.  There will be $2^{n-1}$ different ways to do this for a string of length $n$.

Comment: If that is not the intention, then you will have to explain what additional constraints or symmetries are considered (for example `(aa)(b)(aab) = (aab)(aa)(b)` if we consider two to be equal if the multiset of substrings are equal.)

Comment: The only constraint (which I mentioned) is that the order of the elements is kept, just different possible groupings; so, issues  relating to symmetries are out of the question.

 Knowing the weights of each element in a set, you could get the number of possible combinations, but I don't think that is quite a combinatorics kind of problem, probably more like a topological one, but I am not so sure.

 I could imagine such problems appear in korpora research and genetics, while encoding and analyzing large substrings within strings.
 – lbrtchx

Answer (score 1):

You have $n-1$ locations at which you could insert a break, and these choices are independent. So there are $ 2^{n-1}$ possible splittings, and these are easy to put into 1-1 correspondence with the bit strings of length $n-1$.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you really want is an algorithm that gives all the possible partitions of a given string. Had the string consisted of all distinct symbols and were a $n$ length string, the number of such partitions would have been given by the [Bell number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number) $B_n$. It only remains here to take account of the repeated numbers in the string that would reduce the number of partitions to $<B_n$.

Comment: You have both me let me see that I should have explicitly said: "set of non-overlapping substrings of a string, **which include repeated subdtrings** …" I described it in the example, but didn't explicitly say it in the subject line.